# How to sorting a Multi-Dimensional Array and get value after sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Below is my code. please help!!!

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($product_ref); $i++) {
    $final[$i] = array(
        $i = > array(
            'producer' = > $producer_name[$i],
            'client' = > $client_name[$i],
            'provider' = > $product_provider[$i],
            'product' = > $product_name[$i],
            'status' = > $current_status[$i],
            'planno' = > $plan_no[$i],
            'currency' = > $plancurrency[$i],
            'premium' = > $premium[$i],
            'frequency' = > $paymentfrequency[$i]
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: http://au2.php.net/array_multisort#100534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `$final` looks like `$final->$i->$i->data` so you do not need the first `array($i => ...)`.

Then this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699110/3440545) should help you sort the array.